# Can't implement the logic of Score Counter for quizz App

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a quizz app using Listview the idea of app is having list of question each question has
4 Radio Buttons to choose the answer and after finishing all questions user click submit button 
the submit button move the user to Score layout with his total Score

my problem is : i can't implement the logic of Score Count i added an if condition that work everytime 
a change happed to RadioButtons it check the answer if it right it add +1 to the score
the problem is happening if the user pick the right answer then change it to wrong answer
the score keep the same and if i add counter-- when the answer is wrong the score became negative as there is multiple of wrong answers

```
    final RadioGroup rd = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if (getItem(position).getAnswer() == rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                    counter++;

            }
        }

    });
```

Full Project : https://github.com/engmedo800/QuizzChan6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have some array with booleans, which would hold response correctness for every of the questions, like so:

the array field declaration:

```
private boolean[] isCorrectAnswer;
```

the array field initialization in Adapter constructor (it's called QuestionAdaptor in your project):

```
public QuestionAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questionArray) {
    super(context, 0, questionArray);
    isCorrectAnswer = new boolean[questionArray.size()];
}
```

the code for listener:

```
final RadioGroup rd = (RadioGroup) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        if (getItem(position).getAnswer() == rd.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                isCorrectAnswer[position] = true;
        } else { 
                isCorrectAnswer[position] = false;
    }

});
```

the getCorrectAnswersCount() code:

```
int getCorrectAnswersCount() {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < isCorrectAnswer.length; i++) {
        if (isCorrectAnswer[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help thanks didn't think about that solution =D

Comment: do you have any suggestions to improve my Data Structure and programming skill , i am trying to became an android developer also i started with android basics nanodegree by google

Comment: first of all, I would suggest you to use descriptive names instead of shor ones, e.g radioGroup instead of rd.
Also, by convention, in Java variable names should begin with underscore character, e.g choiceA instead of ChoiceA.
I would also suggest to use RecyclerView instead of ListView.
Last but not least - learn Kotlin language as it's becoming the standard.
If you want example of above things, check out my project: https://github.com/szymonchaber/group-shopping-android
You can also contribute there if you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Count only correct (true) answers - recalculate all answers after each answer of user. In that case you will not have any issue.